# Office 365 Outlook groups domain selection

Tags: office365

I have a new Office 365 for business setup with several Internet domains on it.  When a create a group in Outlook, the default domain is automatically filled in with no way to change it.  If I do it through the admin interface then I can select any of the domains.

The question can I grant my users the ability to create groups that are not in the default domain without needed to get an administrator involved.

This is a simple on-line only setup with no on-premises sync.

Comment: Normal users should not be allowed to create groups, that’s something, only an Administrator should do

Comment: I'm talking Outlook Groups not groups in the active directory.

Comment: I was also.....

Comment: I don't know about should but they can.  Just go to the groups folder in outlook and click the +.  They can also create their own teams.  It just always assigns our default domain.

Comment: Creating groups is normal Office 365 functionality. You can disable it, if you don’t like users doing that. But here is how to do what you are asking: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-the-domain-to-use-when-creating-office-365-groups-7cf5655d-e523-4bc3-a93b-3ccebf44a01a

Comment: I already know how to do it with powershell but that requires admin.  The idea was to enable end users to select other domains right in outlook.  Maybe it just doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is any way to allow users to select which domain they should use themselves, however you should be able to select defaults for different groups of users using *email address policies*:

#### Scenario 1

The following example shows you how to provision all Office 365 groups in your organization in the groups.contoso.com domain.

```
New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name Groups -IncludeUnifiedGroupRecipients -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates "SMTP:@groups.contoso.com" -Priority 1
```

#### Scenario 2

Let's say you want to control what sub-domains Office 365 groups are created in. You want:

Office 365 groups created by students (users which have Department set to Students) in the students.groups.contoso.com domain. Use this command:

```
New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name StudentsGroups -IncludeUnifiedGroupRecipients -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates "SMTP:@students.groups.contoso.com","smtp:@groups.contoso.com” -ManagedByFilter {Department -eq 'Students'} -Priority 1
```

Office 365 groups created by faculty members (users which have Department set to Faculty or email address contains faculty.contoso.com)) in the faculty.groups.contoso.com domain. Use this command:

```
New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name FacultyGroups -IncludeUnifiedGroupRecipients -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates SMTP:@faculty.groups.contoso.com","smtp:@groups.contoso.com” -ManagedByFilter {Department -eq 'Faculty' -or EmailAddresses -like "*faculty.contoso.com*"} -Priority 2
```

All other users in the groups.contoso.com domain. Use this command:

```
 New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name OtherGroups -IncludeUnifiedGroupRecipients -EnabledPrimarySMTPAddressTemplates "SMTP:@groups.contoso.com" -Priority 3
```